# Function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ that is unbounded around any given point?

Tags: functions, special-functions

What is a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ that is unbounded around any given point?

I apologize for my poor translation of the problem. I didn't know the exact words as we don't study math in English ( we really should though! ).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE, I tried to fix wording/formatting. If I went against your intent, please edit as you please. Note that LaTeX can be included within `$latex here$` in your posts. (The latex here was an example)

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function)?  If that is too obscure, my favorite such function is $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational; $f(x) = n$ where $x = m/n$ if $x$ is rational.  For any $x$, $\epsilon > 0$, and $N$ $\in \mathbb N$. We can find an rational$ p/q$ where $x - \epsilon < p/q < x + \epsilon$ and $q \ge N$. (I leave that as an exercise.)  So $f(x)$ is unbounded around $x$ (as $q$ $\ge$ $N$ is unbounded).

Comment: The Conway base $13$ function has the additional interesting property that it takes on every real value on each interval, no matter how small.